# Why doesn't India use the 802.11a wifi standard?

Tags: networking

Why does India not use 802.11a for wifi?

Is the problem power consumption or low bandwidth, or something else?

Comment: Hi Hiren, welcome to SU.  Please could you [edit] your question to clarify what you are asking.  Do you mean the `802.11a` standard?  Do you have an actual problem that you need help with?

Comment: i have some doubts with WIFI 802.11 a standards

Comment: What doubts are these?

Answer (score 1):

Neither power consumption or low bandwidth.

India has avoided 802.11a because the 5 GHz band is used by radar and satellite installations in India.

Onerous Indian regulations to avoid interference with such systems have deterred companies from using 802.11a, but this problem doesn't occur with the 2.4 GHz bands, such as 802.11g and 802.11n(2.4GHz).

Comment: so why in USA or other Countries 802.11 a is used ?

Comment: they used what band for satellite or radar ?

Comment: The USA and other countries chose different bands, or different portions of the 5GHz band for similar operations.  As the USA set the standards at the time, it's just bad luck that India was already using those portions of the band.